# ActionBar Logo in API 21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar

I was using a  **clickable logo** in my `ActionBar` and with `targetSdk 19` (*minSdk 14*) I could use it on `Lollipop` devices. The `Activity` I'm using extends from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

I'm now using `targetSdk 21` and I can't see the logo.

1. Is there a way to show it without refactoring everything to `AppCompat`? Could it still be clickable?
2. If it is not possible, is it a quick refactoring? Or do I have to use the `Toolbar` in every activity? Using the `Toolbar`, how difficult is it to show a **clickable logo**?

Here is the current code in my activity's onCreate:

```
getActionBar().setLogo(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.full_logo));
getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Did you call `setDisplayUseLogoEnabled()` on the `ActionBar` (via `getActionBar()`)?

Comment: I've edited my question with the code I'm using.

Comment: A quick way could be define custom elements inside the Toolbab, but you should evaluate to avoid the actionbar logo in the Material desing.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I'm totally on your side regarding the logo, but that's a precise request from the client. Clicking the logo will open the company's webpage.

Comment: if the app hasn't the navdrawer you can use the menu icon in toolbar

Comment: I went for AppCompat and I'm using Toolbar.setLogo(). I'm now trying to listen for clicks on this logo.

Comment: @DavidCorsalini Can you elaborate little more on how you got this fixed?

Comment: Clicks on the logo are a NO. You can't listen for clicks on the logo.
Toolbar.setLogo() let you  set a logo on the Toolbar.